# Do propeller coefficients go to zero at the same value of advance ratio?

Tags: propeller

Graphs of power coefficient ($C_P$), thrust coefficient ($C_T$), and efficiency ($\eta=JC_T/C_P$) of the 5868-R6 propeller as functions of advance ratio ($J=V/(nD)$) and propeller pitch (blade angle at 0.75R?) are found in many textbooks (such as McCormic):

[image: Power coefficient]

[image: Thrust coefficient]

[image]

From these curves it seems that for a given propeller pitch $C_P$, $C_T$, and $\eta$ go to zero at the same value of $J$. At also seems that the slopes of the $C_T$ vs $J$ curves for higher value of $J$ (where $C_T$ approaches zero) are the same.

I have two questions:

1. Do $C_P$, $C_T$, and $\eta$ always go to zero simultaneously at the
   same value of $J$ for all propellers?  Why?
2. Are the slopes of the $C_T$ vs $J$ curves where
   $C_T\rightarrow 0$ the same for all values of propeller pitch?

Comment: If $C_T$ is 0, then by the definition of $\eta=JC_T/C_P$, $\eta=0$, irrespective of the value of $J$.

Comment: Yes @ROIMaison, that answers one part of the first question.  If $C_T=0$ at $J=J_0$, then $\eta=0$ at $0$ and at $J_0$.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Do $C_P$, $C_T$, and $\eta$ always go to zero simultaneously at the
    same value of $J$ for all propellers?  Why?***

Yes; Talking in dimensional quantities, This speed, at which all coefficients goes to zero is called pitch speed.

At pitch speed thrust goes to zero due to the fact that the incoming airflow drives the apparent angle of attack seen by the blades to zero.

Power = Thrust * velocity , As thrust goes to zero power goes to zero as well.

Efficiency $\eta = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$, $P_{out}$ goes to zero as shown above hence $\eta$ goes to zero.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the first part of my question, @ABCD.  Any thoughts on the second part?

Comment: Hi @Christo, sorry Im not clear what do you mean by the second part. Ct will always be some finite value. it doesnt go to infinity

Comment: Sorry, @ABCD!  It was a typo; I edited the question.  It should be the slope of CT vs J as CT decreases to zero.

Comment: HI @Christo, Not really, the slope depends on the pitch/diameter ratio. You can see this trend in your second image attached. The reason is for a given RPM and diameter, higher pitch propeller has higher pitch speed and hence shallower slope. HTH

Comment: Does a negative power coefficient have any meaning? I.e. can the curves be said to  "continue" below the X axis in any meaningful sense? Asking because in the configuration tables for Microsoft Flight simulator engine and propeller combinations, the table that gives the power coefficient values for different advance ratios and propeller pitch angles, the power coefficient is negative for high J values.