# How to find trim condition of a sectional airfoil without knowing the angle of attack?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, stability, angle-of-attack, variable-pitch

I am using a reflexed airfoil designed for positive pitching moments to achieve a pitching angle matched to the changing of free-stream velocity (Aerodynamically tailored).
I ended up with a pitching moment equation
$$
dM = c*Cm_{a.c} - (C_{l_0}+C_{l_α}*α)*Χ_{a.c}
$$
where $c$ the chord length, $Cm_{a.c}$ the pitching moment coefficient about the aerodynamic center of the airfoil $Cl_0$ the zero lift pitching coefficient, $Cl_a$ the lift coefficient at a certain angle of attack and and $Xa.c$ an offset distance about aerodynamic center.

I want to design a propeller and the data i have is free stream velocity, RPM, and geometry of the blade.
I assume a thin airfoil so the lift coefficient ($(C_{l_0}+C_{l_α}*α)$) is roughly $2π*α$ and $α$ varies with free stream velocity and rotational speed: $α = Δβ - tan^{-1}(V_{inf}/V_r)$ and $Δβ$ the pitch angle.

The idea is to find the ideal angle of attack $α$ that satisfies the pitching moment equilibrium condition $dM = 0$. However, pitching moment coefficient $Cm_{a.c}$ is also **unknown**.

*Let's say $X_{ac}$ value is given.

So, my question is how this equation can be solved? Can i get any other data from the airfoil's profile that help to find the solution?
Are reflexed airfoils have any characteristics that i should consider in such situation?

Comment: I don't understand the chord with the $C_M$, that would make the dimensions not right.

Comment: @Koyovis This comes from the equation 

$$dM = dM_{ac} - dL*X_{ac} = 1/2ρV^{2}c^{2}Cm_{a.c}dr - 1/2ρV^{2}cC_LX_{ac}dr  = 0$$

$C_L = (C_{l_0}+C_{l_α}∗α)$

Comment: Yes indeed. I would expect a length divided by a length, a dimensionless entity, to accompany the $C_M$

Comment: @Koyovis Imagine schematic shown in this link: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/how-to-define-pitch-angle-for-a-passive-variable-pitch-propeller?noredirect=1#comment106318_40910

Comment: Do you want to solve the equation for $Cm_{ac}$ or for $\alpha$? If you have one equation you cannot solve for both. From the title of your question it appears that $\alpha$ is an unknown, however if free stream velocity, rotational speed and twist are known,  then $\alpha$ is known and you can solve for $Cm_{ac}$

Comment: @Koyovis the two variables depend on each other..and if i find one...other can be found from the polars of the airfoil. But, how α can be found by knowing only freestream velocity and rotational speed? Let's say there is no twist at the moment so angle of twist = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to a model of your airfoil, a moment balance, and a wind tunnel, you may determine $C_{M_{ac}}$ experimentally: the moment the wing experience may be normalized to calculate $C_{M_{ac}}$

Then solving for alpha is trivial. Otherwise a tool like XFLR5 may be useful to find  $C_{M_{ac}}$ for your airfoil.

Comment: I believe he's using a symmetrical aerofoil and a NACA profile of which data is published.

Comment: @Koyovis I am using a an EPPLER airfoil with reflexed profile. For symmetrical airfoils i found that pitching moment coefficient is zero, so it doesn't work

Comment: If it is published the pitching moment at ac is usually published

Comment: @user74671 Yes. It is published, but the only thing i can find is a relation between $Cm$ and $α$. http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=e328-il (last plot)

*Pitching moment has to be zero for static stability

Comment: Ok then still find alpha where L=0, look at graph, Cm there is Cm at ac

Comment: with L you mean lift? If so, why am i looking for L=0?

Comment: If you look at your equation in your other question the over all moment coefficient is made up of CMac, and the moment produced by the lift. (Drag would also produce a moment but its small). When L (or CL) is zero, the only moment acting on the foil is that at the aerodynamic center

Comment: The problem is that L (or CL) varies with the freestream velocity. So i suppose that it cannot be zero at any speed condition. However, my idea is similar; to give an initial value to CL and then find corresponding coefficients and α. But, is there any value can be used as Cl starting point for small propellers (≈15 cm radius)?

Comment: Cl varies with alpha. It can also vary at different reynolds numbers. Choose the reynolds bumber you anticipate it to operate at then look up alpha when cl is 0

Comment: @user74671 Ok, thanks..So alpha will be kept constant at any speed condition and is the pitch angle (Δβ) that will change throughout a range of speeds right?

Comment: Sorry i was speaking in a general airfoil sense. I believe i mean pitch angle. I mean the angle of attack of your airfoil on the propeller with the air. It is a little more complicated with a propeller since there is relative velocities between the spinning and the free stream velocity

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned before, angle of attack depends on pitch angle minus the inflow angle: $α=Δβ−tan^{−1}(Vinf/Vr)$. So α will be constant..and Δβ will change according to Vinf and Vr. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I think considering the pitch angle and relative velocities is unnecessary to find the cmac For the airfoil.  At first just consider the airfoil in a 2d sense. You will need to figure out the range of Re #s that it will experience by determining the range of velocities it will see