# What is the definition of "geometric pitch angle" for a propeller?

Tags: propeller

My question is regarding the geometric pitch angle of a propeller. Is it the angle between the rotational/propeller plane and the zero lift line of the particular airfoil at a propeller section? Or is it between the propeller plane and the chord line of the airfoil?

Answer (score 2):

From a variety of online sources (e.g. [1](http://webserver.dmt.upm.es/~isidoro/bk3/c17/Propellers.pdf) and [2](http://www.free-online-private-pilot-ground-school.com/propeller-aerodynamics.html)), the geometric pitch angle is simply the incidence angle between blade reference chord and the plane of rotation.

This makes sense from the definition of [blade pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_pitch), which is the distance that a point on the prop would move forward in one rotation, if it's gripping in a solid medium. The [conversion](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/76922/how-can-i-calculate-the-relationship-between-propeller-pitch-and-thrust/76924#76924) from pitch to pitch angle, therefore, has nothing to do with aerodynamics (i.e. lift) and is geometric only.