# Is "V/n" geometric or effective pitch in advance ratio formula?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller

[image]

**V**   is the freestream fluid velocity, typically the true airspeed of the aircraft or the water speed of the vessel

**n**   is the rotational speed of the propeller in revolutions per unit of time

**D**   is the propeller's diameter

Why in my aerodynamic book from aeronautics  university write  V/n in advance ratio formula  is aerodynamic /"effective" pitch(I agree with that), but some members which are aerodynamics experts at this site said that this is geometric pitch(zero slip)?

example

[image]
[image]

Comment: Uh...I've never said it's geometric pitch...In fact I've specifically told you it's not geometric pitch: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/76922/how-can-i-calculate-the-relationship-between-propeller-pitch-and-thrust/76924?noredirect=1#comment214793_76924

Comment: @JZYL Your first answer,before I get example  with numbers  was that is geometric.And you didnt confirm that is effective pitch...So agree with me and books that it is aerodynamic/"effective" pitch?

Comment: No, you're misrepresenting my answer completely. My answer states: "The geometric pitch (p) is simply the distance that a point on the prop would move forward in one rotation, if it's gripping in a solid medium." That is not V! Air is not solid medium. And double no, that is not effective pitch either.

Comment: @JZYL I never mention your description in post, I only refer to your comments to my question.If it  is not geometric or effective pitch what is it?why would book write wrong?

Comment: I suppose you can call it effective pitch. Seems like plenty of sources define it that way. I would ask that you remove part in your question about me saying it's geometric pitch.